# How to define sslCAFile with MongoDrive

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

how can add sslCAFile to MongoDriver (reactivemongo)

```
import reactivemongo.api._

val driver = new MongoDriver

  val connection = MongoConnection.parseURI(Configuration.mongodbURI).map {
    parsedUri =>
      driver.connection(parsedUri) 
  }.get

  val db = connection(DATABASE_NAME, FailoverStrategy(retries = 20))
}
```

Comment: Have you indicated `sslEnabled`(see connection doc)? P.S.You'd better use `connection.database(..)` instead of `connection(..)`.

Comment: @cchantep it is changed since reactivemongo 0.11.10 . and yes ssl is enabled

Comment: "it is changed since reactivemongo 0.11.10"? And what error do you get about SSL for now?